# How do I measure the execution time of a query running on Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark application that dynamically fetches the coordinates (lat and long) given a set of addresses as input. I want to know the amount of time it takes for the spark to process each address and return results once the query completes its execution. 
I tried logging the events by setting the followings in the spark-defaults.conf file:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled             true

spark.eventLog.dir                 file:///D:/eventLogging
```

The event log file has got generated after running the application. However, I couldn't get what I wanted.
Please someone help on how can I accomplish this.
Thanks in advance.